# Insert a row in a table in redshift database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift database of following structure

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | firstname | subject |   date      | Grade |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | satheesh  | physics |  2017-1-01  |   C   |
| 2  | satheesh  | physics |  2017-2-01  |   D   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to insert a new row into the table for the same user and for the same subject only if user grade changes from the last date. how can I do that?
Ex: for the above rows I can only insert a new row for satheesh and physics subject if grade changes from d to C or D to B

Comment: What's that redshift, is ir your SQL database name?

Comment: Take incoming grade in a variable and use `if exists` with where clause should be name and subject and current date

Comment: @PrashantPimpale https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the values for the `firstname` (let's use `:name` to represent it), `subject` (`:subject` hereafter) and `grade` (`:grade`), you can use an insert-select statement with a query that returns a row only if the last grade is different than the new `:grade`:

```
INSERT INTO grades
(firstname, subject, date, grade) -- Assuming the ID is a serial
(SELECT firstname, subject, CURRENT_DATE, :grade
 FROM   (SELECT firstname,
                subject, 
                LAST_VALUE(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY firstname ORDER BY date DESC)
                  AS last_grade
         FROM   grades) g
 WHERE  firstname = :name AND subject= :subject AND :grade <> last_grade)
```